# break row from foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to break foreach loop.

```
 @foreach($referralData->product as $data)
<tr>
<td>{{$data->id}}</td>
<td>{{$data->price}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Out put of this loop is

```
id 7
price 30$
id 7
price 80$



 id 8
    price 90$
    id 8 
   price 80$
```

What I am trying to do  calculate total of id , 
something like Id 7=110$ and Id=8= 170$.
My problem is loop .I am unable to  break listing of data in foreach.
Please help me if any suitable away where I can calculate data by similller ID.

Comment: Loop twice. First to get the total for each id, then to display id + total

Answer (score 0):

You have to reshape your data so it contains `price` against the respective `id`. You can do this before the loop:

```
$result = collect($referralData->product)->groupBy('id')->map(function ($item) {
            return $item->sum('price');
        });
```

After that, in your loop, do the following:

```
@foreach($result as $id => $price)
<tr>
<td>{{$id}}</td>
<td>{{$price}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```